# FeedsHTTPFetcher: how to parse object to get source url?

Tags: 7, views, feeds

I've got several content-types based on imported RSS feeds (Feeds import, Simple Pie library).

In a Views pre render, I try to display an information stored in `$row->node_feeds_item__feeds_source_config` that looks like this:

```
a:1:{s:16:"FeedsHTTPFetcher";a:1:{s:6:"source";s:38:"http://www.as-e.be/agendas_rss/rss.xml";}}
```

How can I just get the `http://www.as-e.be/agendas_rss/rss.xml` part of that object? I have no idea how to parse that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out a dirty solution to extract an URL from a random string text!

```
preg_match('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $row->node_feeds_item__feeds_source_config, $match);
```